# parametrizing integer quadratic form $ Q(a,b) = Q(c,d) $ where $Q(x,y) = x^2 + 3xy + y^2 $

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

source:   this began by giving an answer at [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565016/prove-that-abcd-is-a-composite-number/4565118#4565118)

This turned  out sneakier than I expected.  I wound up parametrizing  $ Q(a,b)  = Q(c,d) $   by Gauss composition, in the Dirichlet version, as  $(a,b)  = (x,y) \circ (z,w)$   while
$(c,d)  = (x,y) \circ (w,z).$

That is: with positive $a,b,c,d$ integers and $a^2 + 3ab + b^2 = c^2 + 3cd + d^2 ,$  we get an infinite number of examples from
$$  a = xz-yw, \; \; \; \; b = xw + 3yw + yz , \; \; \; $$
$$  c = xw-yz, \; \; \; \; d = xz + 3yz + yw . \; \; \; $$

I think this gives **all** (doubly) primitive examples, as in both $\gcd(a,b)=1$  and $\gcd(c,d) = 1.$

That is the question, does my simple recipe give all primitive examples?  Some references are in Barry Smith's article [Barry Smith](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.2140%2Finvolve.2017.10.541) on Zagier's methods for binary quadratic forms... I know some things  but have no complete proof For instance, it's true if the common value is prime.

NOTE:  it is beginning to seem that this is a consequence of unique factorization in the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q [ \sqrt 5] .$  For comparison: in the rational integers, when some $AB=CD,$   we may define $q = \gcd(A,D)$ and fiddle a bit to conclude that $A = g \alpha, B = h \delta, C = h \alpha, D = g \delta.$

examples:

```
   n = a^2 + 3 a b + b^2  = c^2 + 3 cd + d^2 

        n          a    b    c    d          x    y    z    w        n
        11         2    1    1    2          1    0    2    1        11 =  11 
        19         3    1    1    3          1    0    3    1        19 =  19 
        29         4    1    1    4          1    0    4    1        29 =  29 
        31         3    2    2    3          1    0    3    2        31 =  31 
        41         5    1    1    5          1    0    5    1        41 =  41 
        55         6    1    1    6          1    0    6    1        55 =  5 11 
        59         5    2    2    5          1    0    5    2        59 =  59 
        61         4    3    3    4          1    0    4    3        61 =  61 
        71         7    1    1    7          1    0    7    1        71 =  71 
        79         5    3    3    5          1    0    5    3        79 =  79 
        89         8    1    1    8          1    0    8    1        89 =  89 
        95         7    2    2    7          1    0    7    2        95 =  5 19 
       101         5    4    4    5          1    0    5    4       101 =  101 
       109         9    1    1    9          1    0    9    1       109 =  109 
       121         7    3    3    7          1    0    7    3       121 =  11^2 
       131        10    1    1   10          1    0   10    1       131 =  131 
       139         9    2    2    9          1    0    9    2       139 =  139 
       145         8    3    3    8          1    0    8    3       145 =  5 29 
       149         7    4    4    7          1    0    7    4       149 =  149 
       151         6    5    5    6          1    0    6    5       151 =  151 
       179         7    5    5    7          1    0    7    5       179 =  179 
       199        10    3    3   10          1    0   10    3       199 =  199 
       205         9    4    4    9          1    0    9    4       205 =  5 41 
       209        13    1    8    5          6   -1    2    1       209 =  11 19 
       209         8    5    5    8          1    0    8    5       209 =  11 19 
       211         7    6    6    7          1    0    7    6       211 =  211 
       241         9    5    5    9          1    0    9    5       241 =  241 
       281         8    7    7    8          1    0    8    7       281 =  281 
       319        15    2    9    7          7   -1    2    1       319 =  11 29 
       319         9    7    7    9          1    0    9    7       319 =  11 29 
       341        17    1   13    4          5   -1    3    2       341 =  11 31 
       359        10    7    7   10          1    0   10    7       359 =  359 
       361         9    8    8    9          1    0    9    8       361 =  19^2 
       451        10    9    9   10          1    0   10    9       451 =  11 41 
       451        17    3   10    9          8   -1    2    1       451 =  11 41 
       551        22    1   10   11          7   -1    3    1       551 =  19 29 
       589        20    3   15    7          6   -1    3    2       589 =  19 31 
        n          a    b    c    d          x    y    z    w        n
```